# Помогите составить regexp выражение для PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В переменной может содержаться:
1 день,
2 дня,
5 дней,
19 дней,
21 день,
1-2 дня,
22-27 дней

Если одно число, то получить его, если два числа, то большее.
PS. совсем не могу пока разобраться с регуляркой.

```
 .*\b(\d+)\b.*
```

Спасибо @teran

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/n6vJbu/1  в данном случая с заменой, но вообще без хвоста `.*` и результат в группе 1.

Comment: @Akina я так понял, что получить надо именно число.

Comment: @teran, спасибо! Пошел разбирать, как работает.

Comment: @UModeL панику не разводите )

Comment: @UModeL  а я и следую.

Comment: @UModeL мой комментарий вообще никак об это свидетельствует. свидетельствовать может наличие или отстутствие ответа по итогу

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/n6vJbu/2 может проще использовать матчинг

Answer (score 2, accepted):

извлечь второе число можно с помощью выражения

```
.*\b(\d+)
```

`\b` обозначает границу слова. так что этому выражению будет соответствовать произвольная строка, потом разделитель и искомое число.

в целом вы просто можете вычленить из строки все `(\d+)` и с помощью `preg_match_all('/(\d+)/', $str, $matches)` получите 1 или 2 совпадения. возьмете последнее совпадение из `$matches` - `array_pop($matches[0])`;

на само деле решений может довольно много для этой задачи. Можно например, применить альтернацию сначала поискав пару число-число или просто число

```
(?:\d+-(\d+))|(\d+)
```

второе число из первой маски и просто число из второй вернуть в группу захвата.